# BASH variable and awk inside variable

Tags: bash, awk

I got this simple bash script:

```
#! /bin/bash

DATE=$(date +"%d%m%Y%H%M")

DATETIME=$DATE | awk '{print substr($1,1,2)"."substr($1,3,2)"."substr($1,5,4)", "substr($1,9,2)":"substr($1,11,2)}'

echo $DATETIME
```

The output of variable DATE is e.g.

```
250520141600
```

and the output of variable DATETIME should be:

```
25.05.2014, 16:00
```

but I got nothing.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not working because you did not `echo` the content of `DATE` before piping it to `awk`.

```
>> DATE=$(date +"%d%m%Y%H%M")
>> DATETIME=$(echo $DATE | awk '{print substr($1,1,2)"."substr($1,3,2)"."substr($1,5,4)", "substr($1,9,2)":"substr($1,11,2)}')
>> echo $DATETIME
25.05.2014, 16:07
```

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to use `awk` to format the output. Just do this:

```
$ DATETIME=$(date +"%d.%m.%Y, %H:%M")
$ echo "$DATETIME"
25.05.2014, 15:21
```

That said, you might want to store one date and display it in a number of different ways. To do that, I would recommend using `date`, rather than `awk`:

```
$ DATE=$(date)
$ echo "$DATE"       
Sun May 25 15:39:09 BST 2014
$ date -d "$DATE" +"%d%m%Y%H%M"
250520141539
$ date -d "$DATE" +"%d.%m.%Y, %H:%M"
25.05.2014, 15:39
```

as well as displaying the current date/time, `date` can also be passed a string containing a date and reformat it for you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to invoke a command and put the output in the variable. Since the output has spaces, it should be quoted.

```
DATETIME="$(echo $DATE | awk ...)"
```

Also, why not just adjust the date output to be the format you want?